Place the given chess pieces on the given chessboards so that no piece attacks another
Beginner puzzles
These puzzles are intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to these puzzles.

Place the chess pieces provided on the chessboard provided so that no piece attacks any other.

Puzzle 1:
Place 4 bishops and 1 queen on


Puzzle 2:
Place 3 kings and 3 knights on


Attribution: Erich Friedman

My solutions:

 Puzzle 1: place 4 bishops and 1 queen


 Puzzle 2: place 3 kings and 3 knights




Easy to prove that 1st one is unique as the queen should not attack more than 6 squares.
